# nodejs express ReferenceError: next is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to control the input I took from a form with joi validation. The function `validateCampgrount` is a middleware to check it but when I try to write the next function it says next is not defined.*

Where I am using `next()`

```
const validateCampground = (req, res, next) => {
  const { error } = campgroundSchema.validate(req.body);
  if (error) {
    const msg = error.details.map((el) => el.message).join(",");
    throw new ExpressError(msg, 400);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

Error Message

```
next();
    ^

ReferenceError: next is not defined
```

Where I am using function

```
app.post(
  "/campgrounds",
  validateCampground(
    catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
      // if(!req.body.campground) throw new ExpressError('Invalid Data', 400)
      const campground = new Campground(req.body.campground);
      await campground.save();
      res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`);
    })
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using middleware wrong. See [this tutorial](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) for a full guide.

In your code, you are wrapping a function in your middleware. Instead, you need to pass the middleware as a parameter to `app.post()`. Like this:

```
app.post("/campgrounds", validateCampground, async (req, res, next) => {
  const campground = new Campground(req.body.campground);
  await campground.save();
  res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`);
});
```

Comment: no still same it is not passing the line of next()

Comment: @UmutcanAdıgüzel Can you elaborate?